# error: fallthrough inside functions

Tags: c

I've been learning c for the past few days (still beginner) and i saw some codes like:

```
int func()
{
    code..
    return 0;
error:
    return 1;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what does the `error:` section do, after some time googling i found nothing (i'm not sure what it's called, i assumed it's fallthrought just like in the switch statement). I wrote this simple code to see what it does:

```
int n;
char input[100];
int main()
{
    printf("Type a number: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    sscanf(input, "%d", &n);
    printf("%d", 1/n); // Invoked error by inputing 0

    return 0;

error:
    printf("error busted");
    return 1;
}
```

When i ran it and typed 0 i got a floating point exception but the `error:` section did nothing, so how does it work exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `error:` would get used by `goto error;`, but you have nothing like that in your examples.

Here's a snippet from Linux kernel (namespace.c):

```
static struct vfsmount *fs_set_subtype(struct vfsmount *mnt, const char *fstype)
{
        int err;
        const char *subtype = strchr(fstype, '.');
        if (subtype) {
                subtype++;
                err = -EINVAL;
                if (!subtype[0])
                        goto err;
        } else
                subtype = "";

        mnt->mnt_sb->s_subtype = kstrdup(subtype, GFP_KERNEL);
        err = -ENOMEM;
        if (!mnt->mnt_sb->s_subtype)
                goto err;
        return mnt;

 err:
        mntput(mnt);
        return ERR_PTR(err);
}
```

Using `goto` is prone to errors, discouraged, and not for beginners.

Comment: so without using goto it's useless?

Answer (score 0):

`error:` is a label for `goto`. As you have no `goto` it will do nothing.

You should turn on all warnings in the compiler. Also do not use `goto` - other methods are better